# Output breaking in child Process by nodejs

Tags: node.js, child-process

I connected  [wavecom GSM modem](http://www.google.com/imgres?q=wavecom%20gsm%20modem&um=1&hl=en&sa=N&biw=1280&bih=880&tbm=isch&tbnid=Paht9jLVzyWsrM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.made-in-china.com/showroom/skylinestefanie/product-detailVMuJIZwPrOcG/China-Wavecom-16-Port-GSM-Modem-Bulk-SMS-Modem-USB-RS232-Interface-4-Kinds-of.html&docid=AOTKF8FaBRwPtM&imgurl=http://image.made-in-china.com/2f0j00FZctYUSLaTqI/Wavecom-16-Port-GSM-Modem-Bulk-SMS-Modem-USB-RS232-Interface-4-Kinds-of.jpg&w=450&h=450&ei=2GtpT-WwOMrprAfi7anfBw&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=199&vpy=323&dur=1527&hovh=225&hovw=225&tx=125&ty=128&sig=105577733481107667276&page=4&tbnh=164&tbnw=183&start=71&ndsp=25&ved=1t:429,r:5,s:71) on ubantu. I use node.js language to communicate with GSM modem.
I send command to modem by [Child Process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html). Here example

```
var spawn         = require("child_process").spawn,
    exec          = require('child_process').exec;

 // Write dev_ttyUSB15.tmp file
 var child = exec('cat < /dev/ttyUSB15 > /tmp/dev_ttyUSB15.tmp');

 // Read dev_ttyUSB15.tmp file
 var m1 = spawn('tail',['-f','/tmp/dev_ttyUSB15.tmp']);

 // on data event is emitted when dev_ttyUSB15.tmp file has some data 
 m1.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
     console.log("Data : "+data); // this is executed as output
 });
```

Now When I fire some command on port /dev/ttyUSB15 I do not get output properly.

E.g

Suppose my output should be

```
Data : abcd1234
```

but instead of it I got

```
Data : abc
Data : d1234
```

In short My output is breaked.
I can not extrapolate from where my output exactly break. It's random.
Can anyone give me any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As all streams in node.js, the reading of data consists of 2 separate events: **data** and **end**.

**data** event is fired when some data is readable in the stream (in your case, twice).

**end** event is fired when no more data events will be fired.

```
var blob = "";
m1.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
 blob += data;
});

m1.stdout.on('end', function () {
 console.log("Data : " + blob); // here you have all the data within one variable
});
```

Comment: Sorry but "end" event will fire only when tail process kill externally...And if tail process is killed then I can't listen any data on port /dev/ttyUSB15...

Comment: This may not help in the use case of listening constantly, but for me, this was the key to solving a bug that had been haunting me—only on one environment—for the past few days. Other platforms were giving me everything in the first call to 'data', but now that I'm buffering and only acting after 'end', my code works everywhere, yay!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without knowing what protocol you are speaking with the modem, but if it's e.g. `\n` delimited, you will have to buffer the data and split on `\n`:

```
var buffer = '';
m1.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    var received = (buffer + data).split('\n');
    buffer = received.pop().trim();
    console.log(received.join(''));
});
```

Comment: The key is that `data` will fire whenever it receives "enough".  You need to buffer up the response.  Take a look at Substack's [Stream Handbook](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook) for more details.